# Add Home icons to mobile devices by clicking link

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, icons

I have created a mobile website and it is working fine. Now I am creating a mobile home icon for both iPhone and Android. Is there any way for the user to create the home icon just by clicking a link in the website, rather than going through the bookmark options?

Comment: I found this [blog post](https://medium.com/@sam20gh/how-to-add-add-to-home-screen-to-your-website-4b07aee02676), but the instructions are not much more different from the answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on either Android or iOS.

Your best bet is to use an instructional popup script. There are many of these for iOS online but [cubiq's version](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) seems good.

Android is similar (with the default browser) and I'd recommend a similar solution although I cannot find an Android specific script.

Instructions for doing this on either OS can be found on [this blog](https://www.mavenlink.com/community/blogs/785-add-to-home-screen-for-iphone-ios-and-android). Use with caution, however as the browser the user uses (as well as the OS version for Android) will require very different instructions!

Comment: both links are broken meanwhile :(

Comment: Unfortunately this post is over 10 years old, and with [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) being what it is, this is unfortunately expected.
These answers may also be outdated as specification evolves.

However, these links are on Archive.org:
[Cubiq's iOS popup script](https://web.archive.org/web/20171112225527/http://cubiq.org:80/add-to-home-screen)

[Mavenlink cross-device blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120809034616/https://www.mavenlink.com/community/blogs/785-add-to-home-screen-for-iphone-ios-and-android)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in or standard way to programmatically add a home screen icon from a web page for either iOS or Android.

HOWEVER, you can go a PWA route. This will take some extra work and configuring, and it will still require a prompt to be made to confirm that the user would like to download your web app.

Resources for PWAs:

- [how to add custom install button for pwa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343203/how-to-add-custom-install-button-for-pwa)
- https://dev.to/developertharun/convert-any-website-into-a-pwa-in-just-3-simple-steps-35pp
- https://github.com/mdn/pwa-examples

Comment: My app is already set up to be a PWA.  Unfortunately, the solution provided in your first link is not at all standard and not even on track to be standard.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent