# how to add custom install button for pwa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

i want to add custom `install` button for my progressive web app within the site. i red many articles and tried the answer provided by them. they use `beforeinstallprompt`

```
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    deferredPrompt = e;
});
```

but the problem i am facing is i want the button to directly installed the pwa instead of triggering the installation prompt. is it possible, if so how can i achieve that. thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is, you can't. According to the [manifest spec](https://wicg.github.io/manifest-incubations/#installability-signals):

> By design, this specification does not provide developers with an explicit API to "install" a web application.

Answer (score 12):

Try below code,

Step 1 - Create button or any controller

```
<button id="installApp">Install</button>
```

Step 2 - Add below js code in your scripts noy in serviceworker

```
let deferredPrompt;
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
        deferredPrompt = e;
    });

    const installApp = document.getElementById('installApp');
    installApp.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        if (deferredPrompt !== null) {
            deferredPrompt.prompt();
            const { outcome } = await deferredPrompt.userChoice;
            if (outcome === 'accepted') {
                deferredPrompt = null;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: but this will do the same it will call app installation popup i want the button to directly install the app.

Comment: Hello @kamal as per PWA architecture pwa is browser dependent. So you cannot install it directly without browser prompt. There is no way without PWA default install functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I know it might be late, but I would like to share my answer, in case someone needs it.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const deferredPrompt = e;

            const installButton = document.createElement('button');
            installButton.textContent = 'Install App';
            installButton.style.position = 'fixed';
            installButton.style.top = '10px';
            installButton.style.left = '50%';
            installButton.style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';
            installButton.style.zIndex = '9999';
            installButton.style.padding = '10px 20px';
            installButton.classList.add('btn-grad');
            installButton.style.color = 'white';
            installButton.style.border = 'none';
            installButton.style.borderRadius = '5px';
            installButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';

            installButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

                deferredPrompt.prompt();

                deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(choiceResult => {
                    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                        console.log('App installed');
                    } else {
                        console.log('App installation declined');
                    }

                    installButton.style.display = 'none';
                });
            });

            document.body.appendChild(installButton);
        });
    }
```

This exactly does what you want. And is compatible with most modern browsers.

Comment: Almost same as the top-answer. What's the point of making the button in js?